# Service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./.realm is already registered

Tags: java, deployment, service, jboss

I'm trying to deploy three different ear files to the same Jboss server...

One of them doesn't have a context root, and the other two have it, but it's different. I mean, let's take the three ears as one.ear, two.ear and three.ear:

one.ear has:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

two.ear has:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/two</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

three.ear has none.

When I try to star Jboss (7 AS), I got this:

```
16:01:31,962 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."one-ear.ear"."one.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."one-ear.ear"."one.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "one.war" of deployment "one-ear.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018027: Failed to add JBoss Web deployment service
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarDeploymentProcessor.processDeployment(WarDeploymentProcessor.java:320)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarDeploymentProcessor.deploy(WarDeploymentProcessor.java:114)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./.realm is already registered
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceRegistrationImpl.setInstance(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:154) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.startInstallation(ServiceControllerImpl.java:227) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.install(ServiceContainerImpl.java:560) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:201) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2228) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:201) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2228) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceBuilderImpl.install(ServiceBuilderImpl.java:307) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarDeploymentProcessor.processDeployment(WarDeploymentProcessor.java:269)
    ... 7 more
```

I have read that this error could be thrown when two apps in the same server have the same context root, but this is not the case... what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Generally the containers such as Jboss have a context root of

```
<context-root>/</context-root>
```

to intercept all the incoming requests and pass on to the application server. In your I suspect the conflicting app is JBoss AppServer root itself, you can disable that using the following (enable-welcome-root="false")

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.0">
  <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" socket-binding="http" scheme="http"/>
  <virtual-server name="localhost" enable-welcome-root="false">
    <alias name="example.com"/>
  </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: @Juned, it's not solving the case.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `.war` archive from web server, then deploy again. You can do this through jboss management console. It also could be that you have deployed another application with same value of `<context-root>` element in `jboss-web.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Check which `--server-config` file is used to start the server. In my case that was `standalone-ha.xml` instead of the expected `standalone.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

As of to me, restarting the JBoss Server was enough.
*No idea why.*

Answer (score 0):

this solved my problem  - go to your standalone.xml - the one which is being reffered by JBoss

In the standalone.xml  - you will find the deployment section

```
  <deployments>
        <deployment name="YOUR_APP.ear" runtime-name="YOUR_APP-version-SNAPSHOT.ear">
            <fs-archive path="C:\YOUR_APP-version-SNAPSHOT.ear"/>
        </deployment>
    </deployments>
```

if you are trying to deploy the newer versions or different version of your ear - the it will give such error.

Remove this part from the deployments section and keep it empty

```
  <deployments>
 <!-- remove the deployment from here --> 
    </deployments>
```

then just restart your server - it will deploy the YOUR_APP.ear again

and now it will show it with - NEW version

```
<deployments>
        <deployment name="YOUR_APP.ear" runtime-name="YOUR_APP-NEW_version-SNAPSHOT.ear">
            <fs-archive path="C:\YOUR_APP-_NEW_version-SNAPSHOT.ear"/>
        </deployment>
    </deployments>
```